# Neo4j cypher: combining aggregate, order by and limit

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Relatively new to Cypher and can't see from documentation how to get what I need, which is a combination of ORDER BY and LIMIT with an aggregation, I'm guessing using COLLECT.

Take the following graph:

```
CREATE (colombia {name:'Colombia', pop:50})
CREATE (argentina {name:'Argentina', pop:43})
CREATE (peru {name:'Peru', pop:32})
CREATE (chile {name:'Chile', pop:17})
CREATE (ecuador {name:'Ecuador', pop:16})
CREATE (bolivia {name:'Bolivia', pop:11})
CREATE (paraguay {name:'Paraguay', pop:7})
CREATE (uruguay {name:'Uruguay', pop:3.4})
CREATE (venezuela {name:'Venezuela', pop:32})
CREATE
  (colombia)-[:BORDERS {length:586}]->(ecuador),
  (colombia)-[:BORDERS {length:2219}]->(venezuela),
  (colombia)-[:BORDERS {length:1800}]->(peru),
  (ecuador)-[:BORDERS {length:1420}]->(peru),
  (peru)-[:BORDERS {length:171}]->(chile),
  (peru)-[:BORDERS {length:1075}]->(bolivia),
  (chile)-[:BORDERS {length:6691}]->(argentina),
  (argentina)-[:BORDERS {length:942}]->(bolivia),
  (argentina)-[:BORDERS {length:1880}]->(paraguay),
  (argentina)-[:BORDERS {length:541}]->(uruguay),
  (bolivia)-[:BORDERS {length:750}]->(paraguay)
```

To illustrate what I need consider the query:

```
MATCH (a)-[ab]-(b)-[bc]-(c) 
WHERE a.name = 'Bolivia'
WITH a, b, c, bc
ORDER BY b.pop DESC, bc.length DESC
RETURN a.name, b.name, b.pop, c.name, bc.length

╒═════════╤═══════════╤═══════╤═══════════╤═══════════╕
│"a.name" │"b.name"   │"b.pop"│"c.name"   │"bc.length"│
╞═════════╪═══════════╪═══════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│"Bolivia"│"Argentina"│43     │"Chile"    │6691       │
├─────────┼───────────┼───────┼───────────┼───────────┤
│"Bolivia"│"Argentina"│43     │"Paraguay" │1880       │
├─────────┼───────────┼───────┼───────────┼───────────┤
│"Bolivia"│"Argentina"│43     │"Uruguay"  │541        │
├─────────┼───────────┼───────┼───────────┼───────────┤
│"Bolivia"│"Peru"     │32     │"Colombia" │1800       │
├─────────┼───────────┼───────┼───────────┼───────────┤
│"Bolivia"│"Peru"     │32     │"Ecuador"  │1420       │
├─────────┼───────────┼───────┼───────────┼───────────┤
│"Bolivia"│"Peru"     │32     │"Chile"    │171        │
├─────────┼───────────┼───────┼───────────┼───────────┤
│"Bolivia"│"Paraguay" │7      │"Argentina"│1880       │
└─────────┴───────────┴───────┴───────────┴───────────┘
```

I need to limit the results firstly to the top 2 matching `(b)` nodes by *pop* attribute, then the top 2 `(c)` nodes by `[bc.length]` for each case of `(b)`.  In this example that means rows 1,2,4 & 5.

I've experimented with COLLECT but got nowhere.  Very grateful for assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query:

```
MATCH (a)--(b)-[bc]-(c) 
WHERE a.name = 'Bolivia'
WITH a, b, c, bc
ORDER BY b.pop DESC, bc.length DESC
WITH a, b, COLLECT({c: c, bc: bc}) AS data
LIMIT 2
UNWIND data[..2] AS d
RETURN a.name, b.name, b.pop, d.c.name, d.bc.length
```

returns:

```
╒═════════╤═══════════╤═══════╤══════════╤═════════════╕
│"a.name" │"b.name"   │"b.pop"│"d.c.name"│"d.bc.length"│
╞═════════╪═══════════╪═══════╪══════════╪═════════════╡
│"Bolivia"│"Argentina"│43     │"Chile"   │6691         │
├─────────┼───────────┼───────┼──────────┼─────────────┤
│"Bolivia"│"Argentina"│43     │"Paraguay"│1880         │
├─────────┼───────────┼───────┼──────────┼─────────────┤
│"Bolivia"│"Peru"     │32     │"Colombia"│1800         │
├─────────┼───────────┼───────┼──────────┼─────────────┤
│"Bolivia"│"Peru"     │32     │"Ecuador" │1420         │
└─────────┴───────────┴───────┴──────────┴─────────────┘
```

`COLLECT` is an [aggregating function](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/functions/aggregating/) that uses the non-aggregating terms in the same `WITH` (or `RETURN`) clause as the "grouping key". In this query, `COLLECT` is collecting an ordered list of `c` and `bc` values for each distinct (and ordered) pair of `a` and `b` values. The `LIMIT` clause limits the `WITH` results to the first two `a` and `b` pairs (and their `data` lists).

Comment: Thanks very much Sam. Well that's the right data, but I'm struggling a bit to interpret the query. Is COLLECT vectorising c and bc, and then applying `LIMIT 2` to each separately?

Comment: I've added a paragraph to the answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Sam. Really helpful.

Comment: Sorry to follow up, but do you know if this Cypher expression is evaluate all the `bc` combinations for `bc.length` before it evaluates the LIMIT for `b.pop`? The query on my database is hitting memory limit, whereas the query's final output should be very small.